# python is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, path-variables

I try to install [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) software. For that Python is required.

I installed Python from [here](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/) of name `python-2.7.3.msi`.

I am working on Windows 7.

Hierarchy of my Python software is same as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215810/easy-install-is-not-recognized-as-an-in-internal-or-external-command-operable).

After doing that, I make `PATHVALUE = C:\Python27\Scripts`

When I run any Python file, it shows

> python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   Failed to create vc project files.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: in environment variables add `;C:\Python27`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to append to your `PATH` the string `C:\Python27`, not the scripts folder. Basically, you want the folder with the actual binary `python.exe` on your path.

Comment: ohk, i have done what you said, but it stils show the same error

Comment: yes, I opened new prompt in windows. 
and for your information I download python from here http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.msi

Comment: @jhamb Open up a command prompt and type `PATH` - make sure it's actually there, and the actual location where your `python.exe` binary resides. Try manually running python from the command line as well - simply type `ptyhon`.

Comment: I checked PATH, it shows `C:\Python27`, paath.
but, when i wrote python, it shows the same error

Comment: @jhamb Double check that your Python installation is *actually* in `C:\Python27`. Make sure it's separated from the previous entry in your path by a semicolon, like `C:\foo;C:\Python27`

Comment: @Yuushi: Thanks , Actually I left one space after semicolon. I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Yuushi: That problem is solved. Actually i tried to do this https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation
Now it shows
`Build skipped, To build,  this file have to run from VS cmd prompt`
What can I do now. (I am new in this)

Comment: @jhamb Do you have visual studio installed? If so, go to start -> visual studio -> visual studio tools -> visual studio command prompt, and follow the instructions from there.

Comment: "Basically, you want the folder with the actual binary python.exe on your path." every answer on SO with this issue should have these words

Answer (score 2):

Try this [screencast](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96) or (not a best way) put python executable into C:\Windows\system32 folder.

The better way is to change Windows environment variable.
In short, your path is:
My Computer ‣ Properties ‣ Advanced ‣ Environment Variables

For more details please see [this](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#setting-envvars).