# Invoke script with elevated credentials WITHOUT being prompted for password

Tags: java, python, runas

I am writing a program to invoke a script, [Java to pass args to a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512412/java-to-pass-args-to-a-python-script)

I would like this script to be invoked with elevated credentials WITHOUT prompting me for password. So far, I found the following solution

```
echo Plaintextpassword | runas /user:DOMAIN\privilegeduser cmd /c python ps.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10
```

But it does not work because the console displays RUNAS USAGE.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You get the RUNAS USAGE because the command needs to be a single parameter (that is, enclosed in quotes). I couldn't get the password echo part to work but the runas part is:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\privilegeduser "cmd /c python ps.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10"
```

Comment: this is quite helpful. I'm trying to see if there is a way the program will automatically read in the password without prompting the user to enter it manually

Comment: check out the /savecred option. I haven't used it myself and cant give you much advice except that its used to save the password for later reuse.