# Run python script from C++

Tags: python, c++

I want to run a python script from the c. i tried it compile successfully but it give error "python is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 // main() is where program execution begins.

 int main()
 {
    std::string filename = "hi.py";
    std::string command = "python ";
    command += filename;


    FILE* in = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    pclose(in);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Where (what directory) is your C program running from? Try running python with the full path where it is installed.

Comment: Is `python` in the standard program search path? Can you, from a command prompt and in any directory, start Python by writing the command `python`?

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg it is in the standard program search path.when i type it give python version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433499/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

You  want to use the full path to your python executable, something like:

```
std::string command = "/usr/bin/python ";
```

Comment: still it give "the system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: I just gave an *example*, you have to use *your* path

Comment: I use like this...... std::string filename = "C:/Users/BirunthaG/Desktop/print.py"; std::string command = "C:/Python27/python ";    @  Paul Evans