# Cant find version or use pip using python27 command line

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip, kivy

I have been looking for the past hour regarding installing modules using. It says that python27 comes with pip, However when I type `python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools` into the command line I just get the error `NameError: Name 'python' is not defined.` I cant even enter `python --version`.

The module I am trying to install is kivy. On their website it just say download python and type in that string into the command line and it should work. I cant find anywhere if i need to do something beforehand.

Comment: Are you doing this directly from your Python shell instead of your terminal?

Comment: just try with the command pip install

Comment: Highly suggest using `anaconda`

Comment: Do it from terminal then

Comment: Run `pip` from the shell command-line, not from python.

Comment: Ohh no sorry I am using python (Command Line)

Comment: Run pip install from terminal not shell

Comment: You need to type those commands directly at the command prompt, **not** inside the Python interactive interpreter.

Comment: What happend when enter only "python" then enter?

Comment: @PM2Ring when i do this i get `python is not recognised as an internal or external command`

Comment: enter ONLY "pip install" and check your version of python >=2.7.9

Comment: In that case, you need to fix your PATH, as shown in Akshay Jr's answer.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433499/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @Stages. Just install a fresh version so it is 2.7.12. and I get the same errors and before.

Comment: Why the hack are people not looking to the several hundreds of same questions asked and answered before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to set PATH in environment variable for python command to work.If you're on windows follow this:

My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >
Then under system variables  create a new Variable name PATH.Under value type your python installation directory which includes py.exe etc(scripts folder).Then it'll work.
OR open cmd prompt in python folder(shift+context menu click) and then enter command.