# Trying to use pip install but getting an error python3 is not recognized

Tags: python, pip, attributeerror

I want to get pyfiglet but when I type in `python3 -m pip install pyfiglet` it just gives me an error: `'python3' is not recognized as an internal of external command, operable program or batch file.` I also tried using python instead of python3 but just got an error: `AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'deepcopy'`

Comment: try `pip3 install pyfiglet`

Comment: Looks like you have a path problem where different commands of different versions are being called. I absolutely love pyenv: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv to let me manage locally-installed Python versions. It let's Python2 and 3 coexist (even customize which will be loaded for a given directory), all within your user folder, without messing with system-wide Pythons.

Comment: so I tried pip3 install pyfiglet @VenkataGogu suggested but when I import it into a file I get an error: AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433499/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: The fact that `python3` isn't recognized but `pip3` is recognized suggests big problems, like partially-uninstalled Python versions, incorrect PATH, etc. What OS? I recommend uninstalling as many Pythons as you can and starting afresh, ideally with pyenv (pyenv makes all these problems disappear).